# JMeter script creation using JMeter API & Java code through IntelliJ IDE

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

How to create a JMeter script using JMeter API's and Java Code through IntelliJ IDE ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, be aware that this way of creating a JMeter script is not officially supported so you won't be able to get any help so may be it worth reconsidering your approach before moving forward.

If you still want to do this:

1. Open [IntelliJ IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started.html)
2. Add the [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) .jars (they live in "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation as [dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-project-dependencies.html)
3. Create a JMeter script according to your test scenario

More information: [JMeter Command Line Overview: 5 Ways To Launch a Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-command-line)

Example project you can use as a basis: [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/)

There is also [JMeter Java DSL](https://abstracta.github.io/jmeter-java-dsl/), it doesn't support all JMeter features but it provides handy way of creating and running a basic test plan via simple API

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri for your valuable comment.